# Illegal offset type and invalid argument

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on content-based filtering algorithm using PHP. I'm trying to retrieve user data from the table using the query `"$user = [$db, "SELECT interest FROM jobseeker WHERE username = '$username'"];"` it shows the warning as in comment:

```
protected function processUser($user)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($user as $tag) {
        $result[$tag] = 1.0; //illegal offset type on this line
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Also while fetching objects from the table using the query

```
$objects = [$db, "SELECT job_title, category FROM job_data"];
```

it shows another warning as in comment:

```
  protected function processObjects($objects)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($objects as $object => $tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) //invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
                         {
```

What would be the valid argument for this case??
I've tried this query as for this case:

```
$objects = [($db,"SELECT job_title from jobs") => [$db, "SELECT name FROM categories"]];
```

Still it didn't work as it gave error unexpected on this query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Well, what's inside `$user` and `$object`?

Comment: The $user contains user's preference an $object contains job titles that are similar to user's preference